# Launch mvn exec:java as linux daemon

Tags: linux, bash, maven, process, daemon

I am trying to execute the mvn plugin exec:java as a deamon on linux. When I do it "manually" from the console it seems to work:

```
$ nohup mvn -f $PATH_TO_POM exec:java -Pxyz &
```

launches the daemon and redirects the usual console output to the file nohup.out. I could not figure out what the -P parameter does, but I can use it to find the pid of the launches process and to kill the process

```
$ pgrep -f xyz          # returns some pid, e. g. 12345
$ kill 12345
```

When I try to launch the daemon from within a simple bash script

```
# this is part of bash script in separate file
$ nohup mvn -f $PATH_TO_POM exec:java -Pxyz /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
$ pgrep -f xyz          # returns some pid, e. g. 12345
$ jps -l                # shows that 12345 belongs to org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.laucher.Laucher
$ jps -m                # shows "12345 Launcher -f $PATH_TO_POM exec:java -Pxyz /tmp"
```

it fails, because after executing the file above and then

```
$ ps -p 12345
```

there is no such process with PID 12345, although the script above delivers the PID.

Comment: Why would you like to run the exec-maven-plugin in Daemon mode? For what purpose ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, we want to run it during development such that we can quickly launch the application from the source code without intermediate build steps. The application shell run several days and survive a server restart

Comment: What about using your IDE for such things?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I need to run the application even if the server restarts, and thus IDE is not an option

Answer (score 0):

```
$ nohup mvn -f $PATH_TO_POM exec:java -Pxyz 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
```

without /tmp works